# Baking normal Maps creates weird patches

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I am facing problem while baking normal map from high poly to low poly character.
So I modeled the low poly character first, duplicated it and sculpted in some details using the multi-res modifier.
I then again duplicated the low Poly model, to be used as a cage object.
Then Marked the seams in the low poly model and unwrapped it.
I then put in the image texture node in the shader editor for the material of the low poly model, with color space as non-color. Created a new image with 2048x2048 resolution and 32 bit float.
I then baked the normal map(all three objects were on top of one another), selected to active, with the cage object (cage object was encompassing both the high poly and low poly model) and had kept ray distance extremely small (0.0001).

With all this, the normal map generated has a weird patch(has no details) in it, due to which the final texture on the low poly model looks weird.

Here is the normal map with the weird patch which does not have any details:
[image]

Due to this, if I apply this normal map on the object, the area of the mesh corresponding to the patch stands out. In the following screenshot, I have exaggerated the normal map strength so make it clear:

[image]

Here is my UV unwrapped:
[image]

It looks like I am doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated....Thanks...

Comment: Play with Cage value ...

Comment: There are some other issues (NW quadrant looks like poor agreement between low and high poly) but what you're showing in circled area looks a *lot* like rays didn't hit the high poly *anywhere*.  Unfortunately, it's pretty damned hard to diagnose this without both the low and high poly (and probably cage) to see what they're doing.  BTW, cage is usually redundant with ray extrusion (ray extrusion 0.1 is just like making a cage, then alt-s 0.1.)  "Ray distance" is ambiguous, because it used to refer to extrusion, and is not the same thing as current "max distance."

Comment: Wo... I had been playing around with max ray distance only, thinking extrusion will be taken care by the cage object.....So now I removed the cage object, brought my "max ray distance" to 0 and kept the extrusion to 0.1 and now i see details coming up in that patch and the model looks a lot better (there are still parts, around the paw, where the normal maps has orange/yellow tinge. will probably play around with some values and if couldn't solve it then take it to a photo editor and modify there..??)